# Windows 10: Run virtual desktop on one monitor only?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, virtual-desktop

I currently have an external monitor connected to my laptop. I have four virtual desktops that span both screens.

I would like to have my external monitor have the four virtual desktops, but only have one for my laptop. This way I can change virtual desktops on my external monitor, but keep my laptop on the same screen.

Is this currently possible in Windows 10?

EDIT: I am currently using the built in Windows 10 virtual desktops. For example, I want to go from this...

- Laptop: Desktop 1
- Monitor: Desktop 1

to this...

- Laptop: Desktop 1
- Monitor: Desktop 2 *or* Desktop 3 *or* Desktop 4

Comment: How do you create your virtual desktop; using an app, such as Microsoft Sysinternals Desktop https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops , some other app, or the native Windows 10 desktop creation using Win-Ctrl-D / Win-Tab? Please tell us in the question; add how you do it with [edit]. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Windows only allow a single one of those desktops to be active at a time.  There is no way, to display all four desktops at the same time, using the built-in virtual desktop capability.

Comment: Even with your edits, what you want, is still not possible.  You can only activate one virtual desktop at a time.  Windows only ever has a single desktop by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response, or I'm still not explaining myself clearly. I only want one desktop activated. I know you can't show four desktops at a time. That's impractical. And I also know Windows only has one single "real" desktop, hence the "virtual" in virtual desktop.  Trying to mimic a behavior that Apple has with their "Spaces".

Comment: Well Virtual Desktops isn’t Spaces, so it’s not going to work like Spaces, as I indicated what you want isn’t possible.  You indicated you wanted to display more than a single desktop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do it by displaying the apps on the laptop's screen on all virtual desktops ( Win+Tab -> right click on the window -> Show this window on all desktops.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: +1 and would be great if this could be configured to happen automatically for all windows on a particular display. #dreaming

Comment: Thanks for this. Of all the negative response from OP, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app that can create virtual monitors independently for each physical monitors. So on one physical monitor you can have 2 virtual desktops, and on the other monitor you can have 4 virtual desktops. Works well for me.

The current virtual desktops setup of Windows is too cumbersome I never used it. "Show this window on all desktops" is a solution but if you need to open/close mutiple windows it becomes too tiring.

The program I mentioned above is [Actual Virtual Desktops: Multiple Monitors Compatibility - Independent Virtual Desktops on each Monitor](https://www.actualtools.com/virtualdesktops/)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.