# Out of sight 2nd monitor TV in other room from my laptop. Should I use extended desktop or a virtual desktop? See description

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tv, virtual-desktop, extended-desktop

My laptop is in the kitchen. My TV is in the living room. There's a wall between us. The laptop is also connected to the TV with an HDMI cable. This means that I cannot see the TV from where I am sitting on the laptop. I want the TV to display something different from what is on the laptop screen.

For example, I've been using extended desktop to play videos on the TV while I do my work on the laptop. However, because the TV is in the other room, I cannot see the TV to adjust what is on the screen or change it if needed.

Basically what I'm trying to do is work on my laptop at my desk in the kitchen, but at the same time have a video playing for my daughter, put up activities on the screen for her, etc. and be able to control it and view it all from the laptop so I don't have to get up and walk into the living room every time I want to adjust something on the screen.

Is there a way for me to see what is on my extended desktop? Or should I use a separate virtual desktop that can somehow only display to the external monitor?

Comment: You need a small computer attached to the TV that you can RDP to and run the TV that way

Comment: Does this post help : [Windows 10: Run virtual desktop on one monitor only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1469223/windows-10-run-virtual-desktop-on-one-monitor-only)

Comment: If you don't mind spending some money, Actual Tools Window Manager can create a mirror that you can enable and disable using a keyboard shortcut. This allows you to effectively create a window on your laptop screen that sees what your secondary (TV) displays, allowing you to move your mouse to that screen and see what you control over there. Its probably going to be the easiest solution to implement. They possibly also have the functionality in a dedicated program that is cheaper. I have the full suite so I don't know which one you'd need.

Comment: @harrymc that's not gonna work.

Comment: @LPChip: Actual Tools Window Manager is in that link.

Comment: @harrymc The solution they talk about is about virtual desktops, ActualTools does support Virtual Desktops, but its not what OP asks for. They want to view the content of monitor A on Monitor B, not have a program available on multiple virtual desktops. That's why I suggested the mirror function, to create a small window that continuously copies another area viewed to that window.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use a Chromecast on the TV to stream from VLC for videos or if it is a browser based stream like YouTube most of those will support Chromecast on the same network. Cheap one is about $30.
If it is more than just picture/audio/video you mean by activities could you expand further what they are so I can understand if you need a different option.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that I can think of that will work.

Get a second PC and solely connect that to the TV. Then use something like VNC, Teamviewer or Anydesk to remote control that PC. RDP is not going to work because the moment you connect, the TV won't show anything. You want screen sharing, so that's why I suggested any of these products.

A full PC is of course going to cost a lot of money, but is probably the best solution, as it also means that your laptop is not doing all the work anymore, and you have the freedom to move to a different location without being concerned for the video playing on your TV.

A Chromecast could be used, but is much more limited in what you display on the TV. Where you can do stuff like youtube, you can't play a local video or have a program show its output on the TV easily.

If you want to keep using your laptop and not invest in a dedicated pc, then the best alternative is to use a program called [Actual Tools Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/). This program has a feature called Desktop Mirroring.

You first configure how you want the mirror to work. This can be: part of desktop to window, clone monitor to monitor and it can even set to find a window and mirror that, even allowing interaction with the mirror to interact with the actual area.

After activating (You can do this from the tray icon or define a keyboard shortcut to start/stop the mirror), it will now show in the popup window too.  You can resize the mirror and define a scale.

It is possible to set it so that once you activate it, the TV is mirrored to your laptop's screen entirely (great if you manage this using hotkeys) so you can press the hotkey, and it is as if you are in front of the TV, do your thing, press the hotkey again to stop the mirror, and you are back to your laptop.

You can use a second mirror to create a small peek window, so you can keep an eye on what is happening on the TV while you are working. Allowing you to actually see if that movie is still playing.

[image]